# Pass arguments to a Process after its started

Tags: c#, java, jar

Is there a way to start a Process argument and then after its been called, pass arguments to it (and read the output)?

```
    Process process
    void CalledOnStart()
    {
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"; //or anything, really
        process.Start();
    }

    void UserInput(string input)
    {
        process.passArgument(input); //does this exist?
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use some sort of [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). It really depends on the process you are starting.

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments to your `Process` upon invocation, you should do it using the `Start` method, for example:

```
Process.Start("someArg");
```

For passing it later on, when it is already running, I would recommend using [Named-Pipes Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example.

**From MSDN:**

> Named pipes provide interprocess communication between a pipe server
>   and one or more pipe clients.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no generic way to pass arguments to running process.

Options depend on what process you trying to communicate with:

- for command line processes sending to process' standard input/reading standard output may be an option (need to capture both when starting)
- (Windows only) some processes are COM "automation servers" like Office, IE,.. you may be able to attach to existing process using ROT or start one via automation and control via corresponding automation interfaces.
- (Windows only) some support old DDE protocols
- some support other ways of IPC (inter-process communication) - sockets, named pipes,...
- some support reading updates from config files...

Comment: I was looking for command line processes (primarily jar's). Based on the other answers, I will have to learn inter process communication and not use the `Process` class.

Comment: @daboss42 JARs are JAVA artifacts and you didn't tagged it. I edited your tags.